# How to stop to_csv from changing date format?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, export-to-csv

I am trying to write my dataframe as is to csv. Few of the columns of the dataframe are datetime.

I have used `df.column = pd.to_date(df.column)` to convert dates from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy/mm/dd`, which has worked successfully.

However when I write the dataframe to csv, the date columns revert back to the dd/mm/yyyy format.

Here is how I write to csv, `df.to_csv('~/Desktop/df.csv',date_format='%Y-%m-%d')`

How do I prevent the dates from reverting to the old format?

```
pandas version 0.23
python 3.6 - anaconda spyder
```

edit:

This is how I am reading the csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/sample.csv.gz',parse_dates=True, delimiter='\t', compression = 'gzip')
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] of your problem? When I tried, it worked.  (I'm assuming you mean `pd.to_datetime`, and it's not that that converts dates from one format to another, but one _type_ to another.)

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a problem with how you're opening the csv? For instance, excel might automatically re-format your dates when you open it (This happened on my machine when I tried a minimal example, but the csv itself still looks as expected). Maybe test by opening your csv in a text editor

Comment: @sacul added in how I am reading in the file, and let me test opening the csv. I am using excel to open the csv,  I will use text edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below saves dataframe with date column as csv. (`Jupyter Notebook 5.0.0, Python 3.6.6`)

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as datetime
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
x = ['01/12/2018','01/12/2018','01/12/2018','01/12/2018']
y = ['A','B','C','D']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':x, 'var':y})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
```

Note: Here, the `pd.to_datetime()` format changes it to `yyyy-mm-dd`

[image]

**Convert to required format**

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
df
```

[image]

**Save dataframe as csv**

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', sep=',',index=False)
```

**Opening file in text editor**

[image]

**Opening file in MS Excel may need change of column format as below**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you write it sounds pretty strange. Is it possible that you create a copy of a dataframe and do not apply the date formatting to its column?

Otherwise, to be more on the safe side I would try creating a string column just before writing the `df` with the formating of your liking.

Comment: excel was converting the dates back. opened using a text editor all looks fine